# RXJS get comma separated list from stream object property

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

I have an observable that has objects coming into it.  I want to get a property from each object that matches a filter and create a single comma separate string over all the emissions that has the single property I want.  How can I accomplish this?

What I've tried:

```
data.pipe(
    map(item => item.map(d => d.source === "SomeSource").join(",")
))
```

> Data is of the following type: Observable<MyEntity[]>

> Data = [{id:2,name:'MyName1',sourc:'SomeSource1'},{id:2,name:'MyName2',sourc:'SomeSource2'},{id:3,name:'MyName3',sourc:'SomeSource3'}]

However, this results in an observable string, but I just want a string in this format: `MyName1,MyName2,MyName3`.

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you're trying to do.  is data an array of objects? Are you looking to build this comma separated string from each emission, or is it combined over all emissions?

Comment: Clarifications provided in post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using map will not filter the array. The result of this map is a boolean array.

To create a names string from the filtered items do

```
data.pipe(map(items => 
items.filter(item => item.source === "SomeSource")
.map(item => item.name).join(",") 
))
```

or, you can use reduce

```
data.pipe(map(items =>
    items.reduce((string, item) => {
        if(item.source === "SomeSource"){
            string += ` ${item.name},`
        }
        reutrn string
    }, '')
))
```

Comment: Oversight. I did mean filter instead of pipe. I've setup that first example and I see that it should work, but for whatever reason I'm getting back an Observable<string> and not a simple string.

Comment: data is a sream === Observable. the also return an Observable. If you want to get the string, subscribe to the Observeable

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do what you want:

```
data.pipe(
  map(items => items
    .filter(i => i.source = "SomeSource1")
    .map(i => i.name)
    .join()
))
```

- `filter` only elements with source = to provided string
- `map` to name property
- `join` as comma separated string

working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-66111346?file=index.ts)

Comment: Thanks, but it seems like something is off.  The filter does not produce the expected result.  It returns all three values but should only return the matching source values.

Comment: It only returns the matching ones! I changed the test data in the stackblitz, so they all have a source value of “SomeSource1”